# ReactJS What's wrong 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong in my code react

```html
export const BeritaView = ({ match }) => {
  const article = articles.find(item => item.id === match.params.id);
   console.log(articles, match.params.id);
   return(
      <div>
          <h3> News ID: {match.params.id} </h3>
          <h4> {article.title} </h4>
          <p> {article.content} </p>
          <Link to={`/berita`}> Back to Berita dan Kegiatan </Link>
      </div>
   )  
}
```

error calls this :

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please share your webpack config

Comment: Where are you importing `BeritaView`. It seems you've imported that somewhere between the code....

Comment: @SakhiMansoor i dont use webpack  , i just use pure react

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar maybe i import in route.jsx later

Comment: lustoykov answer should help you.

Answer (score 67):

You get this error mostly when you miss a closing bracket in your react code.

Comment: Your answer is the best and to the point I had also the same error and actually this was the mistake which you have mentioned.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Whoa. That worked like a charm. Saved my day. Thanks mate.

Comment: This solved my error. Thank you

Comment: My Webstorm didn't highlight a not closed bracket. The best answer but I don't understand why IDE didn't see this funny issue

Comment: May the universe smile on you.  Would never have figured this one out on my own.

Answer (score 15):

**ES6 Modules are static. This means that `export` / `import` can not appear inside functions, conditional statements or contain variables. This is mostly for efficiency reasons.**

The error means that you have nested somewhere your `export` - probably inside a function.

---

The static structure is enforced syntactically by modules being allowed top-level only, never nested. Implications are that the code structure is known at compile time which allows for dead code elimination, slimmer bundle size and faster lookups.

I recommend reading [this](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#static-module-structure).

Answer (score 6):

Most of the time I encounter this error and this happens when you miss a bracket.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Please consider adding code that resolves the issue. Moreover, it is already mentioned in the accepted answer. Please consider deleting your answer as it does not add new information to this post.

Comment: Haha good call. What a funny way of saying the function is missing a closing bracket. Worked for me +1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all brackets closed.

See an example

```js
const MyComponent= () => {
  return (
    <>Data</>
  );
}; /* <--- like this bracket */

export default MyComponent;
```